# LdapException: Invalid DN Syntax (34) Invalid DN Syntax

Tags: c#, active-directory, .net-core, ldap

I am trying to configure my .Net Core 2.0 app to allow users to be able to change their passwords using the [Novel LDAP](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard) package. However, the LdapConnection.Modify method is throwing the following error.

> Error: LdapException: Invalid DN Syntax (34) Invalid DN Syntax 
>   LdapException: Server Message: 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100225,
>   problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8349, best match of:
>           `'(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberOf=cn=CaptainPlanet,ou=users,dc=company,dc=com))'`

I know the filter is okay because I was able to run it in powershell as shown below

```
Get-ADObject –LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberOf=cn=CaptainPlanet,ou=users,dc=company,dc=com))"
```

Here's my LDAP code

```
public class DomainController
{
    ... 

    public static void WithLdapConnection(Action<ILdapConnection> actionOnConnectedLdapConnection)
    {
        using (var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection())
        {
            ldapConnection.Connect(_server.Address, _server.Port);
            actionOnConnectedLdapConnection(ldapConnection);
        }
    }

    public static void WithAuthenticatedLdapConnection(Action<ILdapConnection> actionOnAuthenticatedLdapConnection)
    {
        WithLdapConnection(ldapConnection =>
        {
            ldapConnection.Bind(_server.RootUserDn, _server.RootUserPassword);
            actionOnAuthenticatedLdapConnection(ldapConnection);
        });
    }
}
```

And here's the calling method

```
public class UpdateUserCommand : ICommand
{
    ...

    public void UpdateActiveDirectory(string newPassword)
    {
        DomainController.WithAuthenticatedLdapConnection(lc =>
        {
            LdapAttribute attributePassword = new LdapAttribute( "userPassword", newPassword);
            lc.Modify( modifyDN, new LdapModification(
                LdapModification.REPLACE, attributePassword) );
        });
        _logger.LogInformation("AD Account: Updated");
    }

    ...
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: I think this is confusing... Modify operation doesn't use a Search filter. So I would guess that the error is in a search operation somewhere (possibly the baseDN?) before the Modify.

Comment: Yep. That was exactly the issue. Figured it was a simple solution. Thanks.